# Django multi forms page with modal form

Tags: django, forms, modal-dialog, popup

how to submit popup modal form values to session without other fields/forms validations?

multi forms page:

{% bootstrap_field bi.climatic_conditions class="mdb-select" layout='outline' size='sm' %}

Add own weather conditions

Click
me*

```
                    <div class="modal fade" id="costomWC" tabindex="-1"
                         role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                    <h4>Custom Weather Conditions</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> &times;</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    {% include 'calculator/custom_weather.html' %}
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                     <a href="{% url 'custom_weather' %}">
                                        <button type='button'>TEST</button>
                                     </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved, missed to place each form in separate

<--form action=""><--/form>